# C# - Can I initialize before the Main starts?

Tags: c#, static, constructor, program-entry-point

I had a job interview with the following question:

Add/Change the following program such that the M method will be called before the Main.
You may not change the Main.

```
Main
{
    c C = new C()
}

Class C
{    
    Public C()
    {
    }

    Public M()
    {
    }
}
```

So I wrote M as a class and then changed Public M to be a static constructor, but that doesn't work in C#, only in C++.
I searched the net, and couldn't find any way to init something before the Main starts.

Thanks...

Comment: The question does not make sense. You can get `M` to be called before `C` is instantiated though.

Comment: Is Main like in `public static void Main()`?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing some bits there - if an interviewer gave you that, you don't want to work there. :)

Comment: Is M supposed to be another class, or a 2nd constructor for C?

Comment: Actually the solution is to use inheritance. Make C inherit from a different class, and override M in C. Then you can call M in the parent constructor and it is called before the C constructor.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can

write a class initializer of `Program` class and put the code before you calling main, then call main yourself.

```
partial class Program {
    static Program(){
        // do something
        Main();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```